# $("#renters-form").submit() is not working in Chrome browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-plugins

Maybe it is duplicate question but I haven't get any answer yet,I'm submitting one form with two different action urls.
First time form submit but second time form is not submit,it is happening only in chrome browser.

Form tags:

```
<form class="form-vertical" id="renters-form" action="/renters/media" method="post">
```

I have two buttons.

```
<input type="button" class="btn button-next" id="next" name="next" value="Continue" />

<input type="button" class="btn button-next" id="previewprofile"  value="Preview Profile" style="display:nonoe;" />
```

First time this code is working and form will be submit.

```
$("#next").on('click', function(){
        $("form").submit();
    });
```

but second time

```
$("#previewprofile").click(function(){
        alert('test');
        $("#renters-form").submit();    

    });
```

not working , form id is `renters-form`

Why form is not submitting in chrome browser?

Comment: form name is renters-form or the form id is renters-form ;) ?

Comment: does it alert for you?

Comment: Show the html for the `renters-form`.

Comment: Please include your form tags. From the sound of it you've got `<form name="renters-form">` when you need `<form id="renters-form">`.

Comment: I'm using yii framework and bootstrap extension

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You stated that you set the name to "renters-form" and you are trying to reference it as an ID.

We would need more info to confirm whether or not it was a grammatical error or not.

Comment: 2 questions:  1: can you show me the form tags?  2:  Is the form#renters-form added to the DOM?

Comment: <form class="form-vertical" id="renters-form" action="/renters/media" method="post">